# Get selected ngModel value in Angular / Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

How can I get the selected option in constructor / function, using Angular / Ionic 2?

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="qty">
        <ion-option value="1" selected="true">1</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2">2</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="3">3</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<button ion-button full (click)="addToCart()">Buy Now</button>
```

I've tried this:

```
export class ProductPage {
    qty: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }

    addToCart() {
        console.log(this.qty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="qty">
        <ion-option [value]="1" selected="true">1</ion-option>
        <ion-option [value]="2">2</ion-option>
        <ion-option [value]="3">3</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

try this

```
export class ProductPage implements OnInit{
    qty: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.qty);
    }
}
```

Please read : https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: It returns `undefined`. I've added `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';`.

Comment: Try the updated code. This code is just to direct you in the right direction . Please review the documentation of ngOnInit and implement it in your scenario.