# How to set selected item in a dynamic options list in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm getting very confused with this, what I'm trying to do is to show a "pre-selected" option in a dynamic options list that I create by using ngFor angular directive in my ionic app

Right now I have this

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Number of Guests</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let person of gests" value="{{person.id}}" selected="{person.id[2]}">{{person.id}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

as you can see, I'm trying to show an item as pre-selected before the user picks one. But I don't have very clear how to do it. Any idea for this?

Comment: I think this is where you would want to use ng-if, to check if the item is of index two and if so set its selected property.

Comment: I think you should uset ngModel on <ion-select> element.
Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937133/9386610

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an index to the loop, so you can choose which option will be the default just specifying the index:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let person of gests; let idx = index" 
  [selected]=" idx == 0 ? true : false"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is actually what I needed, so now the next challenge would be to use a js variable located in my .ts file, and print it in "idx" as its value, in order to "pre-select" the item that matches with this js variable.

Comment: Hi Dolarpami, you can do it just replacing the '0' I put as example by the variable name with the value you want, meanwhile it's defined in the same component .ts

Comment: of course! my doubt comes when I have to do it, because, how can I print js variables into html, let me search and I'll let you know if I find the solution

Comment: ok almost go it, so I have my variable already prepared to be injected in a html tag such as <h1> for example... I do it like this {{variable}} and it works, but when I try to do it replacing the "idx" my app crash, templates getting errors etc etc. Is there another way to display it?

Comment: Hi Dolarpami, You have not to replace the idx variable, this is necessary to go through the loop, you have to replace the variable compared in the condition (in the example, '0'). `[selected]=" idx == variable ? true : false"`

Comment: Sorry, a wrote mistake, I wanted to say "0" I'm actually replacing it with my variable like this [selected]=" i == {{var}} ? true : false" but it is not working since it sems that I can't bind variables in that condition because the app result in a template error interpolation. Any other way to put it in order to print its value without errors inside this condition?

Comment: Hi Dolarpami, Write your var without the `{{}}`. The content in this section is already interpreted as javascript and picking the data from the ts

Comment: finally! thank you very much bro, It works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Tou can use ngModel in ion-select component

```
// html
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson">...

// ts
selectedPerson = gests[0].id;
```